# Accessibility Compatible Formatted Time String

Tags: ios, swift, date, formatting, voiceover

Has anybody an idea how to get formatted time strings from iOS which can be spoken in a natural way by voice-over?! Tapping the clock on the lock screen speaks a perfect localized version of the current time. It is hard to get this right plus it seems that currently, it is not possible to get the following localized `spell out` time strings for the time 12:45 pm:

- DE - "12 Uhr 45"
- EN - "12 o'clock" (or "zero-hundred and 45 minutes" for 00:45)
- FR - "12 heures 45"

I tried with the following pice of code (which just gives you 12:45) as well as the DateComponentsFormatter. But nothing provided the expected results.

```swift
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.formatterBehavior = .behavior10_4
formatter.timeStyle = .short
formatter.dateStyle = .none
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
formatter.string(from: Date())
```

Comment: The problem you have to customize VO for time for each supported language to achieve what something that Apple uses for their clock. This is just impossible since alredy German and English have so different pronounciations of this...

Answer (score 2):

> Has anybody an idea how to get formatted time strings from iOS which can be spoken in a natural way by voice over?!

Dates and numbers must be **well formatted** to be perfectly understood by the VoiceOver users.
Use the elements hereunder and take a look at these [code snippets](http://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#date-time-and-numbers) *(Objc + Swift)* to figure out how to implement an impeccable read out.
[image]

Using your example, I suggest the code hereafter based on the code snippet linked above:

```
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "06/12/2019 12:45")

let hourComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour,],
                                                     from: date!)
let mn = Calendar.current.component(.minute, from: date!)
hourLabel.accessibilityLabel = DateComponentsFormatter.localizedString(from: hourComponents,
                                                                       unitsStyle: .spellOut)! + String(mn)
```

With this rationale, you can have a formatted string compatible with the way you wanted VoiceOver to read out specific time.

Comment: Well, I saw this too and I must admit it is the most informative website about this topic. But is doesn't even come close to a natural language time string. The components formatter speaks the units `hour` and `minute` but what we want is something liek the iOS clock where Voice Over speaks `Twelve o clock`

Comment: The natural language you're looking for can't be natively provided by VoiceOver because it isn't formally defined.
The only way to reach your goal is to customize your accessibility label like the example I added in my post.

Comment: Yeah, but I ask myself why does Apple provide a valid Voice Over experience for their clock but doesn't make it public for the rest of us :-(

Comment: I think that basic tools are provided to create any desired experience for a11y: I agree it's sometimes frustrating to notice that APIs should be more supplied (especially with VoiceOver) but it forces me to try and better understand how everything works... and other developers are here to help if need be.  ;o)